# How to combine ErrorDocument and redirect in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301, errordocument

I have a very simple 5 page static site.

Instead of a 404, I want to do a 301 redirect to the index page whenever a visitor accesses a page that doesn't exist. I tried something like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 404.htm
redirect 301 404.htm index.htm
```

but that doesn't seem to work.  How would I get it to do a 301 redirect to the index page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only a fixed list of pages then you could do something like:

```
#map _all_ known pages on the site
RewriteRule url1 page1.htm [NC, L]
RewriteRule url2 page2.htm [NC, L]
RewriteRule url3 page3.htm [NC, L]
RewriteRule url4 page4.htm [NC, L]
RewriteRule url5 page5.htm [NC, L]

#if there's something that doesn't fit in the rules above then it means there's no such page so we redirect to home with a 301
RewriteRule (.+) index.htm [R=301,L]
```

Comment: or: RewriteRule url([0-9]+) page$1.htm [NC, L]

Comment: That was only an example as he could have 5 pages called `one`, `two`, `three`, `four` and `five` which would have to be rewritten to `first.htm`, `second.htm`, `third.htm`, `fourth.htm` and `fifth.htm`. You can't do this with one rule.